# Issue in calling a particular DIV from HTML hyperlink within same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am editing my question to make it more simple. Please have a look at the below code:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-a">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-b">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-c">Third</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rcitation ullamco laboris nisi</div>
<div id="tabs-b">et ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce</div>
<div id="tabs-c">interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus.</div>
</div>
```

The above tabbed browsing is working fine with the help of jQuery.
Now I want to access those tabs with some external links in the same page, for example:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#tabs-a">First</a>
    <a href="#tabs-b">Second</a>
    <a href="#tabs-c">Third</a>
<div>
```

But it is not working. Please help!

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle including your jQuery?

Comment: Does your console show any error?

Comment: You mean you have some Javascript that is called on load, but it doesn't get called when simply changing the `#tabs-xx` bit? If that's the issue, then sorry, but that's how it's supposed to work. What does the Javascript routine do exactly? Maybe there's a css-only solution based on `:target`.

Comment: No errors.. Nothing is happening on the page

Comment: @speetje33, I can't. It is a very long code which divided into 2 jQuery files. But I don't think jQuery has anything to do with plane anchor tag. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I don't understand your question I think, you just want to go to the DIV when clicked on a link?

Comment: @All, 
I have an "about-us" page in which I am using tab design for every inner-pages of "about-us" say "Goals & Purpose", "The Gaps" etc, for this tab design I am using jQuery so that individual inner-page content can be displayed when its tab is clicked. It is working fine. I am able to call individual DIVs from another page as below:
    <a href="about-us.html#tabs-b">The Gaps...</a>
I have a jQuery drop-down menu at the top of every page. So when I click inner-page link from the same page, i.e. "about-us.html", it is not activating the related Div content from the tab design.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $("#atabs1").click(function () {
                $("#tabs-a").css("display", "block");
                $("#tabs-b").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-c").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-d").css("display", "none");    
            });

            $("#atabs2").click(function () {
                $("#tabs-a").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-b").css("display", "block");
                $("#tabs-c").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-d").css("display", "none");
            });

            $("#atabs3").click(function () {
                    $("#tabs-a").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-b").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-c").css("display", "block");
                $("#tabs-d").css("display", "none");
            });

            $("#atabs4").click(function () {
                $("#tabs-a").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-b").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-c").css("display", "none");
                $("#tabs-d").css("display", "block");
            });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mY2Rn/)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a bit just for the convenience.
I have changed the id's of your div so that it goes easy in the jquery section.
your div id is changed from `<div id="tabs-c" class="content">` to `<div id="databs1" class="content">` just to match with the id's of `li`.

HTML

```
 <div id="tabs">
   <ul>
    <li><a class ="h" id="atabs1" href="#tabs-a">Goals &amp; Purpose</a></li>
    <li><a class ="h"  id="atabs2" href="#tabs-b">The Gaps...</a></li>
    <li><a class ="h"  id="atabs3" href="#tabs-c">Output</a></li>
    <li><a class ="h"  id="atabs4" href="#tabs-d">Challenges</a></li>
  </ul>


<div id="databs1" class="content">
    <h2>Goals &amp; Purpose</h2>
    <h3>This page is under construction! Please come back soon!</h3>
</div>
<div id="databs2" class="content">
    <h2>The Gaps...</h2>
    <h3>This page is under construction! Please come back soon!</h3>
</div>
<div id="databs3" class="content">
    <h2>Output</h2>
    <h3>This page is under construction! Please come back soon!</h3>
</div>
<div id="databs4" class="content">
    <h2>Challenges</h2>
    <h3>This page is under construction! Please come back soon!</h3>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
 $('.h').click(function(){
      var a = this.id;
      a = 'd'+a;
      $(".content").css("display", "none");
      $('#'+a).css("display", "block");

  });
```

I hope the above code will help you and I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Here is the

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mY2Rn/3/)**

Comment: I have no problem at this point. It is working fine in my case as well. My issue is I am not able to activate individual Div (tab) from a drop-down menu of same page.

Comment: @user3405976 so the above solution did not solve your prob? what else are you looking for ? The above solutions will work for individual div (tab) as well.

Comment: I mentioned it in my comment and first post as well. I want to activate individual Divs(tabs) by clicking a drop-down menu in the same page, which is not happening, though the address bar of the browser changes accordingly for example, if I click "The Gap" hyperlink within that drop-down menu the address bar of the browser changes as "file:///F:/about-us.html#tabs-b", but the DIV(tab) is not responding

Comment: @user3405976 And did you apply the `h` class to all `<a>` elements, or only to the ones in the `<ul>`?